# failed to launch apache.spark.master

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

Whenever i run **start-master.sh** command on my local machine i am getting following error please someone help me to fix this issue

#### Terminal Error

Error which i get in terminal

```
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /usr/local/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.6/logs/spark-andani-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-andani.sakha.com.out
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

#### Log Error

If i check the spark log file following is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkMaster' failed after 16 retries! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkMaster' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
   at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
   at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is due to your sparkMaster was not able to contact to your internal IP

- Once check your /etc/hosts file weather it pointing to proper host name or your previous IP address might have changed.
- Reconfigure it and run the command once again.